# How to Create a Web Service to Run In Android and Discoverable and Accessible by .NET

Tags: android, android-webservice

I would like to create a web service that run in Android device. The web service should discoverable. I am searching around how to build a web service in android, but so far always direct me to resources that show me how to consume other web service from android. I'd like to know where to begin.

Comment: Why would you want to run a web service from a mobile device?

Comment: I am in project to controlling devices with android embedded system. So any android devices will discoverable and connected to a "control server", and the "control server" will have access any function / capabilities of the device, such as restart, shutdown, change ip, load web content, etc. I believe these capabilities should be exposed by the android as a web service.

Comment: I think what you need is GCM(https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). Write an agent, which runs on the device and accepts the commands through push messages from the server.

Comment: This good resource. Thank you..! But it seems require the android device to keep online to the internet. What if in local network scenario?

Comment: Look at some async messaging frameworks like MQTT.